# Change background-colour in parts of sourcecode with Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, roslyn

I am a bit confused, because I didn't find any information about colouring with the editor services of Roslyn. Probably I used the wrong phrases and expressions.

I would like to change the background-colour of words or blocks in my source-code, after my analysis with Roslyn. The highlight possibility to underline parts with a type of "error", "info" or "warning" is not what I am looking for! Maybe you can provide me with an idea or the information where to start!

I use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Roslyn Vers. Sep. 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ClassificationProvider sample.  Classification is the term that the VS editor uses for syntax coloring.

Comment: Many thanks @ kevin! Looks very helpful so far, I will try to use it for my purpose.